# How to deal with output transformation at inference/prediction time?

Tags: predictive-models, data-transformation, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, back-transformation

Suppose A machine learning model (e.g. `RandomForest`) which uses $x$ as input and produces $y$. Now as part of preprocessing and feature engineering, I applied some transformation on the inputs and target/output variables. As a result, now I feed $x^{'}$ and $y^{'}$ to `RandomForest`. During training time, I can easily transform the true targets $y_{t}$ to $y^{'}_{t}$ (before feeding them to `RandomForest`) and then inverse transform $y^{'}_{p}$ to $y_{p}$ because I know what $y_{t}$ looked like. But at inference/prediction time, how can I transform the predicted values $y^{'}_{p}$ back to normal scale $y_{p}$ then? The problem is illustrated below

[image]

For some transformations such as `log`, this is easy because I know, all I have to do is to take `exp` of predicted values $y^{'}_{p}$ to bring them to normal scale $y_{p}$. But for many other transformations such as 'minmax' I can not transform back until I know properties of the original data.

Please not that I am not talking about difficulty in interpreting the transformed output/target variable which has been discussed here in other posts but about, how to even transform back the predicted results.